# Does Tom Ellis perform his own musical numbers?

Tags: lucifer

In the TV series Lucifer, the devil is played by Tom Ellis. His character runs a night club and he sometimes plays the piano and sings. There are even some episodes where he does this in other contexts.

So, the devil seems to have some of the good music in this world.

But does Tom Ellis perform the singing and piano playing when these scenes are shot or is he miming to someone else's performance?

Comment: *devil seems to have some of the good music in this world*, yes, he said so.in the episode of how he comes into L.A. He also said something about punishing people in hell using music by *some fella named bieber*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2016, Lindsay MacDonald asked that same question ([TV Query](http://screenertv.com/television/tv-query-lucifers-tom-ellis-play-piano-real-life/)):

Piano:

> "I'm very musical, and I can play a little bit, but piano was never my instrument," he tells us. "Hopefully people believe I'm actually tinkling those ivories."

Singing:

> "The singing is definitely me," Ellis clarifies. "The singing is all me."

And from another source (Brittany Frederick for [Fansided](https://hiddenremote.com/2016/04/18/lucifer-star-tom-ellis-takes-us-hell-nice-way/)):

> “I’ve never learned to play the piano,” he said. “It’s me singing but it’s not me accompanying myself, let’s put it that way.”

A bit more on his musical background from another interview with Emma Brown in 2015 ([Interview Magazine](https://www.interviewmagazine.com/culture/tom-ellis)):

> **ELLIS:** My mum was a music teacher. I’ve got three sisters and we all played instruments when we were kids.
>
> **BROWN:** What did you play?
>
> **ELLIS:** I started on the trumpet and then I upgraded to the French horn. I played in orchestras my entire teenage years. But, on the drama front, no, not really. My dad, strangely enough for this job, was a Baptist pastor, so I grew up in the church as well. I suppose there is a dramatic element to his job, and he enjoyed doing amateur operatics.